# How To Add The Value Of A Static Mesh Component From C++ Instead Of The Unreal Editor?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

New to Unreal Engine here, but not new to c++. In the tutorials I saw, the way they created the `UStaticMeshComponenent` was by first using

```
mesh = CreateAbstractDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(TEXT("Mesh"));
```

and then opening up the unreal editor and setting the shape of the mesh manually. For example, select the drop-down box and select "cube" or something. However, this seems a little inconvenient for me, since every time you drag and drop the actor into the level, you need to manually change the shape of the static mesh. I was wondering if it is possible set the shape from c++ itself. For example, something like this:

```
mesh->SetStaticMesh(Shapes::Cube);
```

Of course that isn't a real method, `Shapes` isn't a real namespace, and `Cube` isn't a real object. But what method and what parameters can I use to make this possible?

Comment: The simplest route is to create a blueprint that inherits your C++ class, and set the mesh default there. You can do it in C++ but it's a pain in the ass, you'd have to find the reference path to your mesh and load it (loading synchronously will trigger a flush forcing everything currently being loaded to also load synchronously). The way around that is to load asynchronously and make sure the mesh stays reference counted.

Comment: I created the blueprint, but how can I set the default mesh there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to attach the component to your actor's root via:
`mesh->SetupAttachment(RootComponent);`

After that reference your static mesh. This is done via:
`const ConstructorHelpers::FObjectFinder<UStaticMesh> MeshObj(TEXT("/path/to/mesh"));`

Afterwards simply call `UStaticMeshComponent::SetStaticMesh` like this:
`mesh->SetStaticMesh(MeshObj.Object);`

Comment: Thanks! All though my days of messing around in Unreal Engine is long gone, if I do come back I will find this useful.